# Invalid UTF-8 sequence in header valiue when connecting to SignalR via WebSocket on Android 4.4 but works from Desktop Chrome

Tags: android, websocket, signalr

I'm struggling to get a WebSocket connection to SignalR (2.1.1) on Android 4.4.4 device (or emulator) within a Cordova app (or as a web app in the mobile chrome browser) but can from Chrome on my desktop.

The error appears to be thrown by the  `connection.socket = new window.WebSocket(url);`:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxx/yyy/signalr/connect?transport=webSocket…22%3A%22aaaahub%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22zzzhub%22%7D%5D&tid=8' failed: Invalid UTF-8 sequence in header value
```

I captured the request/response headers from Fiddler, incase it helps:

```
GET https://xxx/yyy/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=T1LxyZpMcYZM3Cr7HSOoQM%2F6NbkcEoQiYfKZjy72Rqtk8QG%2B08Voo3siYJpxyV7cAuvUNqXEDUGOmMiedhLPmbMTw9%2FyfAfPU8mgdBw6lPstP1WOW1nu7AJTSFvL%2F16b&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22alertshub%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22yyyhub%22%7D%5D&tid=8 HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: xxx
Origin: file://
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 6VBfaOLz30d2Qhe+v8QPXg==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits, x-webkit-deflate-frame
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; Google Nexus 5 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 1080x1920 Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
Cookie: --- Auth cookie snipped---
```

The response headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: Websocket
Server: 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: DR4gXdx5czhn/knKQo8xPB3FJa4=
Connection: Upgrade
Date: Wed, 12 Nov 2014 13:53:46 GMT
EndTime: 13:53:46.287
ReceivedBytes: 31
SentBytes: 0
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else hit's this issue, it's because the Server header was blank.